# Inverse of Euclidean distance in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, distance

Using ArcGIS Desktop I am trying to do the reverse / inverse of a euclidean distance. For example, I am doing distance to roads analysis. The output from the distance raster shows roads as 0 and areas closest to roads as 0.1, 0.2, etc and the areas furthest from roads as a very high value. However, I would like the raster to be the reverse of this - the areas closest to the roads should have the highest values and the areas furthest from the roads should have the lowest values.

How do I create a raster that reverses the number?

I would use reclass but this would be difficult to use as the values are continuous and not integers.

Comment: Can you invert your image before doing the distance transfer? I.e. swap all the 1's for 0's and vice versa.

Comment: You could invert the distance by using the maximum distance value - distance raster, this would give very high values near your features and very low further from your features. You can get your maximum distance from your raster statistics if not already specified in your euclidean distance function.

Comment: Hi Michael and Jon! Thank you but unfortunately neither one of these worked. When I swap 1s for 0s, I get a result that is not accurate - the roads take up such a small portion of the raster that this does not work.  When I specify a maximum distance in the euclidean distance function, it still gives me higher values furthest from the roads and low values closest to the roads. It just truncates the entire distance that it calculates out to.

Comment: Thanks Luke! I also found out that the method below worked, from posting on a different forum. I just am posting it here, in case it is helpful to anyone. The moderators can feel free to take down the link if it is not allowed. 
  https://community.esri.com/message/749843

Comment: In fact the answer in GeoNet says exactly the same thing: `maximum of the raster - raster value`... which is what @user2856 and @Michael Stimson said.

Comment: @user2856, do you mind answering this question???

Comment: @user2856, thanks, upvoted already.

Answer (score 1):

- [Calculate Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-statistics.htm) on the Euc Dist raster (to populate maximum),
- In the [Raster Calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm):

```
"eucdistraster".maximum - "eucdistraster"
```